# SQLSTATE[28000][1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:NO)

Tags: php, sql

When I try to connect to my backoffice in my website I get this error :

```
SQLSTATE[28000][1045]Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'(using password:NO))
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: You want to connect to your database with root user ? THE root user ?

Comment: NO, actually i have a login and password, i don`t understand why he mention the root story !! i can say that this cause no problem under windows (wamp) but under Mac OSX i got this error (mamp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use a password. Try to set one with "mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD"

Comment: i work in localhost and i don`t use a password to my MySQL database servor, i got any problem when i run under windows but when i go under Mac OSX this error appear to me :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply a password when logging into your database.  When you connect to sql from php, make sure you're supplying this password.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a root password previously, but have forgotten it, you can set a new password.  I am working on a Windows machine, and was able to reset the password on the root of MySql using the directions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html.  I created a text file (mysql-init.txt) as follows:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('[choose your password')
WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

At the command line, I entered the following (either make sure you are in the mysql\bin directory or that your path environment variable includes a path to that directory), which will start the server:

```
mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --console
```

This printed out a bunch of status statements.  To stop the server, I typed this in another command line:

```
mysqladmin –u root –p[choose your password] shutdown
```

Of course, replace the [choose your password] with the same password you used in the mysql-init.txt file.  In the first command line, you should get more status statements that indicate that the server is shutting down.

Now that you have a password for your root user, you can go back to the connection statement you are using to connect to the database and add the password and user.